# Angularjs datatables rendering before data is fetched

Tags: angularjs, datatables

```
angular.module('SomeApp').controller('userListsCtrl',userListsCtrl);

function userListsCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder,DTColumnBuilder,$http,$q) {
    var vm = this;
    function serverData() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $.ajax({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'url': 'cgi/userNavLists.py',
            'data': JSON.stringify({'request':"INPROCESS"}),
            'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR, fnCallback){
                console.log("User Table Data Coming Up");
                console.log(data);
                defer.resolve(data);
            },

        });

        return defer.promise;
    }

   serverData().then(function(data){
        console.log("Promise Data");
        console.log(data);
   });
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('cgi/userNavLists.py').withFnServerData(serverData);
                console.log("User Table Data Coming Up123");
    console.log(vm.dtOptions);
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('requestId').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('requestType').withTitle('Type'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('identifier').withTitle('Identifier'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('domainName').withTitle('Domain Name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('recordType').withTitle('Record Type'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('state').withTitle('State'),
    ];


}
```

I am trying to render table fetching data from server. But my table is getting render before data is being fetched.I used promise to do the job but seems it ain't fulfilling my problem. Is their a way I can make it work???

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `$.ajax` and not `$http`? I don't think `$aja` is needed

Comment: I am comfortable using $.ajax, so...........otherwise no grudge using $http

Comment: Ok, I would have into sticking the angular way but .... Anyway, you can get rid of the `$http` reference in your factory ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your object together with the asynchronous response:

```
angular.module('SomeApp').controller('userListsCtrl',userListsCtrl);

function userListsCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder,DTColumnBuilder,$http,$q) {
    var vm = this;
    function serverData() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $.ajax({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'url': 'cgi/userNavLists.py',
            'data': JSON.stringify({'request':"INPROCESS"}),
            'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR, fnCallback){
                console.log("User Table Data Coming Up");
                console.log(data);
                defer.resolve(data);
            },

        });

        return defer.promise;
    }

   serverData().then(function(data){
        console.log("Promise Data");
        console.log(data);
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('cgi/userNavLists.py').withFnServerData(serverData);
                console.log("User Table Data Coming Up123");
    console.log(vm.dtOptions);
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('requestId').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('requestType').withTitle('Type'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('identifier').withTitle('Identifier'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('domainName').withTitle('Domain Name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('recordType').withTitle('Record Type'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('state').withTitle('State')
    ];
   });
}
```